# Getting warning when using `addres of` operator with array as an initializer to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning C and I am having some troubles to truly understand arrays and pointers in C, after a lot of research (reading the K&R book (still reading it), reading some articles and some answers here on SO) and taking tons of notes along the way, I've decided to make a little test / program to prove my understanding and to clear some doubts, but I'm yet confused by the warning  I am getting using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    char *p   = &a;

    printf("%p\n", a);       /* Memory address of the first element of the array */
    printf("%p\n", &a);      /* Memory address of the first element of the array */
    printf("%d\n", *a);      /* 1 */
}
```

Output compiling with GNU GCC v4.8.3:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type                                                                                   
char *p   = &a;                                                                                                                                     
            ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
0x7fffe526d090                                                                                                                                        
0x7fffe526d090                                                                                                                                        
1
```

Output compiling with VC++:

```
warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[3]'

00000000002EFBE0
00000000002EFBE0
1
```

Why am I getting this warning if `&a` and `a` are supposed to have the same value and compiling without warnings when using just `a` as an initializer for `p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&a` is the memory address *of the entire array*. It has the same value as the address of the first element (since the whole array starts with the first element), but its type is a "pointer to array" and not "pointer to element". Hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize a `char*` with a pointer to a `char[3]`, which means a `char(*)[3]`.

Unsurprisingly, the compiler complains about the mismatch.

What you wanted to do is take advantage of array-decay (an array-name decays in most contexts to a pointer to its first element):

```
char* p = a;
```

As an aside, `%p` is only for `void*`, though that mismatch, despite being officially [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), is probably harmless.

Comment: @newacct: Yes. But that does not actually help for variadic arguments, as there's no prototype asking for it.